How to stop the coroutine if the flag bool is false and re start it when true in the Update?
now it's not effecting the coroutine. when i start the game and the flag bool spawn is false or true if i change it at runtime it's not changing the coroutine.  if the coroutine is already working it will not stop it and if it's not working it will not start it.
i  tried to use oldSpawn for this but maybe it's not the right way to use it ?
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.PlayerLoop;

public class SpawnObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Prefabs To Spawn")]
    public GameObject prefabToSpawn;

    [Header("Terrain Settings")]
    public Terrain terrain;
    public GameObject spawnedTerrainObjectsParent;

    [Header("Spawn Settings")]
    public bool spawn = false;
    public int numberOfObjects = 100;
    public float duration = 1.0f;
    public float yOffset = 0.5f;
    public bool isParent = true;

    private float terrainWidth, terrainLength;
    private float xTerrainPos, zTerrainPos;
    private float yValTerrain, randXTerrain, randZTerrain;

    private bool oldSpawn;

    void Awake()
    {
        oldSpawn = spawn;

        if (terrain != null)
        {
            terrainWidth = terrain.terrainData.size.x;
            terrainLength = terrain.terrainData.size.z;
            xTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.x;
            zTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.z;

            if (isParent && spawnedTerrainObjectsParent == null)
            {
                spawnedTerrainObjectsParent = new GameObject("Spawned Terrain Parent");
            }
        }

        if(spawn)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Generate());
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(oldSpawn != spawn)
        {
            if(spawn)
            {
                StopCoroutine(Generate());
                StartCoroutine(Generate());
            }
            else
            {
                StopCoroutine(Generate());
            }

            oldSpawn = spawn;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Generate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            randXTerrain = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth);
            randZTerrain = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos, zTerrainPos + terrainLength);
            yValTerrain = terrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randXTerrain, 0, randZTerrain)) + yOffset;

            GameObject objInstance = Instantiate(prefabToSpawn, new Vector3(randXTerrain, yValTerrain, randZTerrain), Quaternion.identity, spawnedTerrainObjectsParent.transform);
            objInstance.name = "Terrain Spawned";

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
        }
    }
}


Does this answer your question? Can't stop a Coroutine in Unity

To stop a coroutine, you need to have a reference to that specific coroutine. StopCoroutine(Generate()) won't do the trick here.
So, have a reference to your coroutine and stop it using that reference, e.g. like so:
// Reference to a coroutine
private Coroutine coroutine;

// Some function where you start your coroutine
private void RoutineStartedInHere()
{
    ...
    // Reference coroutine when starting it
    coroutine = StartCoroutine(SomeCoroutine());
}

// Some function where you stop your coroutine
private void RoutineStoppedInHere()
{
    ...
    // Stop coroutine using stored reference
    StopCoroutine(coroutine);
    ...
}

// Some coroutine
private IEnumerator SomeCoroutine()
{
     ...
}

